# Plugin errors android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, version

Seems to be one error with gradle version which I don't know how to fix.
I am using android studio. Not very knowledgeable, so will need basic instruction on how to fix this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finalyearrowingapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: please add logs

Comment: Where can I find logs?

Comment: view >> tool windows >> build

Comment: The logs are included there, the code in the question is what comes up when I follow those steps.